# What does the [0] do in $("#id")[0]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm guessing that it's an array index, but from what array?I've seen it used in code like this:

HTML:

```
<canvas id = "id"> </canvas>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
```

What is the purpose of specifying the `[0]` part and how does it differ from doing `var canvas = $("#canvas");`?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a means of returning the DOM node from the jQuery collection, and a shorter way of writing `document.getElementById('canvas')` (albeit using a library to do so), or `$('#canvas').get(0);`.

Effectively it returns the zeroeth-element, the first (using JavaScript's zero-indexed numbering) element, from the collection of objects returned by the jQuery selector syntax.

The *difference* is that `$('#canvas')` returns a jQuery object incorporating a collection of elements (wrapped in a jQuery object with jQuery methods), whereas `$('#canvas')[0]` returns the DOM node, which has access to DOM methods, but not jQuery methods.

References:

- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

Answer (score 2):

It is basically a shortcut notation for [`.get(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

> The `.get()` method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object. If the value of `index` is out of bounds — less than the negative number of elements or equal to or greater than the number of elements — it returns `undefined`.

But actually, jQuery objects are array-like objects -- they contain integer and `length` properties. In fact, [`jqObj.get(index)` internally uses `jqObj[index]`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ca0086b55a158d8a4347f94254878d6dc5dd90ed/src/core.js#L61), just that `.get(index)` is an abstraction level which also handles negative values (counting backwards from the last element).

---

So, `$('#canvas')[0]` lets you access the element contained in the first index of your jQuery object, which happens to be a [`HTMLCanvasElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement). Provided there is an element with the "canvas" ID, both of these methods will return a reference to the same DOM element:

```
$('#canvas')[0] === document.getElementById('canvas')
```

This way, you can access the canvas' native properties and methods, such as `.getContext('2d')`.

Comment: That sounds a little as if using [`[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) would call a `get` method…

Comment: @Bergi well, you know it is actually the other way around. Each jQuery object also masquerades as an array, so `$o.get(index)` just uses `$o[index]` internally.

Comment: Yeah, *I* know, but the OP might not :-)

Comment: @Bergi yes, it is well explained in the linked docs page, I just don't want to copypasta the whole page. `=]` I'll add a bit more of data just in case anyway.

Comment: @Bergi I've added a paragraph about the `.get(index)` abstraction, thanks for the feedback.